# Displaying live graph from JSON input

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a json array of pulseID. I want to use this JSON array to be displayed in a line graph.
1.the x-axis should be the time interval.
2.the y-axis should be the pulseid

```
    Connection con= null;
    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://databasename","root","password");
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List Healthdetails = new LinkedList();
    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
    String query = "select * from data";
    PreparedStatement pstm= con.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pstm.executeQuery();
    JSONObject hObj = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
    int pulid = rs.getInt("pulse");  
    hObj = new JSONObject();
    hObj.put("pulseid", pulid);
    Healthdetails.add(hObj);
        }
 responseObj.put("Healthdetails", Healthdetails);
 out.print(responseObj.toString());

}

catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{

if(con!= null){
try{
 con.close();
 }catch(Exception e){

 e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, this will enhanche the chance someone can help you.

Comment: How did you format your code? It looks really bad.